# How to get CPU usage in MySQL per user?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, cpu-usage

I want to know is there anyway to get CPU usage per user in MySQL? for example I have 3 different users 'user1', 'user2' and 'user3'. I want to get the average/real time memory usage and CPU usage of these users.I googled a lot but I did not find any suitable tool. Maybe I can get these data from MySQL queries, but I don't know where are they stored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: Are these MySQL users or OS users? Are you looking for the OS cpu usage or usage within MySQL?

Comment: i want OS user CPU usage  in Percentage or Frequency.

Answer (score 0):

From a *nix perspective, you can only get the `mysql` user statistics so basically what *all users of MySQL* are doing on the system.

To get individual *Database User Statistics*, you need to dig into the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-system-variables.html#sysvar_performance_schema_users_size) or take this question to https://dba.stackexchange.com.